Create tag synonym from [htm] to [html]
There is a tag htm which has around 6 questions, which most likely should be retagged to html. The same situation appeared in 2018, see Should the [htm] tag be truncated?
It looks like it was cleaned up back then, but then the tag htm got recreated (most likely by accident). To avoid this in the future (again), there should be a synonym link from htm to html. Or we could blacklist the tag htm, so it doesn't get recreated again.

Merged into html, deleted htm, synonym created.
